# Android studio How do I make visibility gone for other user looking at someone's profile Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

When the user visits another user's profile the activity switches but that profile can be edited and so on it is not private mode. so i want the visibilty removed for some parts. only for that profile that the user visits. Otherwise, for example, I have to make a new activity private but that all takes time I think there is another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user only accessable some certain properties from another user, you can do comparison.

Let's say `userA` want to access `userB` profile. Once the `userA` signed in, you need to store his/her `uid`, maybe using [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).

```
final String userUid = FirebaseUser.getCurrentUser().getUid();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.user_uid), userUid);
editor.apply();
```

Once the value stored, and then `userA` visits `userB`'s profile. You need to retrieve `userB`'s information including his/her `uid`. So I assume you already have the `userB uid`. Then, at the `onCreate` you can do comparision check whether this is current user or not. After that, you can edit certain properties for this user.

```
final Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
   userBUid = intent.getExtras().getString(getString(R.string.user_b_uid));
   btnEdit.setEnable(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much